# Jump to relevant section when option from drop down is selected

Tags: jquery, css

I was wondering if i could get some help. What i am trying to achieve is this.

Once an option from the selected, the page should jump to the corresponding div. I am able to do an alert to make sure the right div is selected but i do not know how to make the page jump to the relevant section

```
<div class="nav">
    <div class="top-nav">           
        <form action="#">
            <select>
                <option value="ten">10</option>
                <option value="twenty">20</option>
                <option value="thirty">30</option>
            </select>   
        </form>     
    </div>
</div>


<div class="area">          
    <div id="ten">Alot of content goes in here</div>
    <div id="twenty">Alot of content goes in here</div>
    <div id="thirty">Alot of content goes in here</div>
</div>



$('.top-nav').children().children('select').bind('change', function () {        
    alert($('#' + $(this).val()).html()); 
});
```

Comment: When you say jump do you mean scroll to that div?

Comment: Looks like they are doing the same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6677069/54356

Comment: i meant like page jump, think of those options as anchors <a> instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**demo** there will be slight difference see here: http://jsfiddle.net/byRRY/5/

Behavior in demo select the value and you will see the offset will go to correct div, feel free to remove alert.

This should help,

**code**

```
$('.top-nav').children().children('select').bind('change', function () {  
  $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $('#' + $(this).val()).offset().top}, "slow");

    alert($('#' + $(this).val()).html()); 
}); 
​
```

Comment: Thank you..I really like the effect of this. Now i got to test across browser including mobile..fingers crossed

Answer (score 2):

use scrollto function 
like `$('#mydiv').scrollTo('#somethingelse');`

Comment: This requires the scrollTo plugin

Answer (score 0):

JQuery's scrollTo plugin can achieve this with lots of fun options.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $target = "#myDiv";

    //target, speed, easing
    $.scrollTo($target, 800, {easing:'easeInOutQuint'});
});
```

[The Plugin](http://flesler.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html)